# How can you point in memory to 3 locations if you are having an int pointer?

Tags: c, embedded

I am wondering how can you point to 3 locations in memory if I have an int pointer. If you have a pointer that points to an integer: `int * p ; int i ;` `p=&i`.(if you consider that int points to 2 locations and char to only one) You want to point to only 3 locations in the memory. What do you do ? Can you cast it to char* and after that increment it?

Comment: What do you mean by "point to 3 locations"? What do you mean by "point to 2 locations" or "point to one location"? Do you mean the size of the types? As returned by `sizeof`? Please edit your question and elaborate and give more details. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Pointer is only pointing to a one location.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think the questioner is referring to alignment.

Comment: I think you are seriously confusing the meaning of _point to_ with something else.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the size of the object being pointed to with the pointer.  A pointer points to a single location in memory (say address 0x12300).  It could be that you have a char (an 8-bit value) at that location, so some other variable is at address 0x12301, or it could be a 16-bit value, in which case your program will be compiled to use the value of the 8 bits at 0x12300 and the 8 bits at 0x12301 as a single value.  Or it could be that you have an array (of any size--3 chars or 1000 long words--it doesn't matter).  But the pointer itself will only hold the value 0x12300 no matter how much memory it is pointing at.  It is the compiler (and the machine code it generates) that cause pointer dereferences to be treated differently depending on what they are pointing at.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer points only one variable address at a time. In your case  data type is int, so pointer will point only 2 bytes or 4 bytes memory depending upon compiler ( 16 bit or 32 bit).

Comment: int * p; 
 int i; 
 char c; 

 p = &i; 


 char*ptr = (char*)p; 
 ptr = &c; 
 printf("%p\n", ptr); 
 ptr = ptr + 2;
 printf("%p\n", ptr);
I meant I want to

Comment: Imeant I wanted to use a char pointer instead an int pointer by casting it. Because if I had used only int I couldn't move to 3 locations without casting to char. Char pointer is on 1 byte , while int pointer depends on the architecture, the sizeof(int) can be 2,4 or more.

Comment: that's correct..but what made you to use pointer to point three memory locations.also you can void pointer so that casting is not necessary but you can not retrieve the value of that particular location using void pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is worded somewhat unconventionally, but I guess you mean a pointer to three consecutive bytes?

```
char data[3] ;
char* p = data ;

p[2] = 3 ; // same location as data[2]
*(p + 1) = 2 ; // alternative to p[1]
```